# Configuring log4net to connect to an initially offline database engine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, log4net, adonetappender

I have a windows service set up with log4net, logging to a file and a SQL Server database.

During initilization, I do my `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` call. Early on in the service, I execute some logging. It's a windows service, so it's starting up around the same time that SQLServer starts up. My service is doing logging before the DB is up. When the DB is up, log4net has given up logging to the DB and it fails to proceed.

I'd like for log4net `ADONetAppender` to start appending to the log database as soon as the database is online. Is this possible? Can I just call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` when the DB is back online?

```xml
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:\Logs\MyLog.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1"/>
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      <connectionString value="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tests_db;Integrated Security=True"/>
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES&#xD;&#xA;       (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)"
                                                                       />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawUtcTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="32"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%t"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="512"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%p"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="512"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%c"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="4000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%m"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="2000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to mark your service as depending on SQL server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The service depends on SQL Server being active. If there is some way to define the windows service in such a way that it doesn't start until after SQL server starts, I am unaware of that.

Comment: Yes, every service can have a list of other services on which it depends. If you configure Service A to depend on Service B, then when you start service A, B will automatically be started if it is not already running. If you stop B, then A will also be stopped. If you restart B, then A will be stopped, then B, then B will be started and finally A will be restarted. See http://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed for how to set the dependency if not done at install time.